# WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD and WM_CHANGECBCHAIN ​uses a lot of memory if I copy multiple times. in my program C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, clipboard, wndproc

I use a clipboard monitor. Because of this I noticed that wndproc is a memory leak without putting down garbage collection. But mentioned that more of me requires CPU is an alternative to this code to have less memory usage if I copy something?

I want the copy memory usage to not hold too much, there is another alternative than using garbage collection?

**This is my code.**

```
[DefaultEvent(nameof(ClipboardChanged))]
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : Control, IEquatable<ClipboardMonitor>
{
    private IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;

    public ClipboardMonitor()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Red;
        Visible = false;

        nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Clipboard contents changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ClipboardChangedEventArgs> ClipboardChanged;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            _ = ChangeClipboardChain(Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // defined in winuser.h
        const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
        const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                {
                    OnClipboardChanged();
                    _ = SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    break;
                }
            case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                {
                    if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                    {
                        nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _ = SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }

                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);

    private void OnClipboardChanged()
    {
        try
        {
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            ClipboardChanged?.Invoke(this, new ClipboardChangedEventArgs(iData));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(ClipboardMonitor other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class ClipboardChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    internal readonly IDataObject DataObject;

    internal ClipboardChangedEventArgs(IDataObject dataObject = null)
    {
        if (dataObject is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataObject));
        }

        DataObject = dataObject;
    }
}
```

and this is my wndproc code now

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // defined in winuser.h
        const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
        const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                {
                    OnClipboardChanged();
                    _ = SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    break;
                }
            case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                {
                    if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                    {
                        nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _ = SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }

                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

let me know what I can improve on this code.

Comment: I cannot express how bad of an idea it is to call `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();  GC.Collect();` from a Windows message handler. That is regardless of the fact that you don't even rely on GC when working with unmanaged objects.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem even is, but I would start at fixing the `SetClipboardViewer` declaration `IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer)`.

Comment: @GSerg after which do I have to change that line?

Comment: @GSerg I have a program in which I return things based on what is copied and if I just copy a lot, the ram usage only gets more. that's the problem. and that's why i used garbage collection that's the problem.